# Access a function variable outside the function with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print the value of "gas" outside my function.

Already tried without global and also gave a print statement like `print (gas)`. Nothing works for me.

```
def action(pin):
    global gas
    gas = 1
    print('Sensor detected action!')
    return

action(1)
print gas
```

The result is:

```
print gas   
NameError: global name 'gas' is not defined
```

(Edited) The Complete Code is

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import httplib, json
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Connecting gas sensor with pin 16 of Raspbery Pi 3
gas = None #Initializing gas value as 0


def action(pin):
    gas = 1
    print('Sensor detected action!')
    return gas

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

# print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
time.sleep(1)

temp = '{0:0.1f}'.format(temperature)
hum = '{0:0.1f}'.format(humidity)


GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING)
GPIO.add_event_callback(16, action)


#print '{0:0.1f}'.format(temperature)
#print '{0:0.1f}'.format(humidity)

if temp == 0 or hum == 0:
    #print "ERR_RANGE"
    headers = { "charset" : "utf-8", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("heatexchangelive.000webhostapp.com")
    sample_1 = { "nodata" : no_data }
    sampleJson_1 = json.dumps(sample_1, ensure_ascii = 'False')

    conn.request("POST", "/rpi1/rpi.php", sampleJson_1, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.read())
    conn.close() 
    exit(0)   
else:
    #Sending the data to the server
    headers = { "charset" : "utf-8", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("heatexchangelive.000webhostapp.com")
    print (gas)
    sample = { "humidity" : hum, "temperature" : temp, "gas" : gas }
    sampleJson = json.dumps(sample, ensure_ascii = 'False')
```

And the result I'm getting is,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python tempNew.py
None
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
New record created successfully
alive
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
Sensor detected action!
```

And my DB is always updated with 0 in "gas"

Here is the screenshot of Database,

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is5tM.png)

Comment: Why are you passing the parameter `pin` into the `action()` function when you won't use it? Try to avoid global variables. Maybe you can pass `1` into `action()` function, and return the `gas` variable (and remove the global). Then you can "catch" the returned value of `gas` in the global scope by saying `gas = action(1)` or even directly print by saying `print(action(1))`.

Comment: Is that the entire script? In particular is there a `gas` variable defined anywhere in the global scope? (There isn't in that snippet.) If there isn't, that's why you get this error.

Comment: Are  you sure you're using Python 3? I ask because `print gas` -> `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.` Did you mean print(gas)? If I change that it works without error and prints `1`.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce the issue. Please post a proper MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You could `return gas` and then change your print statement to `print action(1)`

Or you have to define your gas variable outside of the function and then you can use your global statement.

Answer (score 0):

just declare gas variable with None in top.

```
gas = None;

def action(pin):
    global gas
    gas = 1
    print('Sensor detected action!')
    return

action(1)
print(gas)
```

Comment: While it's indeed better to explicitely create globals at the top-level instead of relying on a function call creating them (well, it would be better to not use globals at all but that's another debate), this is not _necessary_ for the OP's snippet since he does call the function before. IOW, the OP's snippet doesn't reproduce the issue...